# How to git pull for multiple repos on windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, github

So I have a lot of repos, and sometimes I forget if some are behind on their pulls, so I was wondering if there was a way to git pull for each repo in one .bat script. I saw someone do it for Linux I believe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in), but I'm on a Windows machine. Does anyone know how to do this for Windows?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make a .bat file in which you add all the repositories yourself with this

```
cd C:\path\to\git\repo
call git pull
cd C:\path\to\git\repo2
call git pull
```

Or let it run through a whole directory with git repositories

```
FOR /D %G in (C:\Documents\GitRepos\*) Do cd %G & call git pull & cd ..
```

Instead of .bat file there is a GUI client [Github for windows](https://windows.github.com/)

If you have all your repositories in there it won't be a pain to remember to sync them all.

Comment: If that is not an option try the techniques described here: http://addyosmani.com/blog/backing-up-a-github-account/

Comment: I used the app in the past, but I find it so clunky, at least for me, in the time that it takes for me to open the app I could've synced a couple by command line. But the link looks really useful!

Comment: I believe this is exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099564/make-a-shell-script-to-update-3-git-repos

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I have edited the answer a bit to incorporate a better answer

Answer (score 26):

Here is a PowerShell version

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | foreach { Write-Host "`n■ Getting latest for $_ ↓" -ForegroundColor Green | git -C $_.FullName pull --all --recurse-submodules --verbose }
```

Comment: I went a bit further and created an alias in my PS profile to call `Git-Pull-All` with this sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806921/228160

Full gist -> https://gist.github.com/yzraeu/12b96c409ae7da29b1a41ddccec3a0c3

Comment: For macOS bash version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786488/10158227

Answer (score 12):

I really liked @eikooc 's answer - and wanted it to work - but it wouldn't work for me on Windows 10.

Here is my variation:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b C:\Documents\GitRepos\') do cd /d C:\Documents\GitRepos\%%f & call git pull & cd ..
```

Answer (score 3):

If you got Git installed with MinGW (bash) you can execute this command that works in parallel:

```bash
ls -d **/* | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it gave me the answer I was looking for and wanted to share what I did for my use.

In a command prompt pointing to directory with repos

```
for /f %f in ('dir /ad /b %cd%\') do cd /d %cd%\%f & call git pull & cd ..
```

Batch file (UPDATEALL.cmd) saved in directory with repos

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b %cd%') do (
    cd /d %cd%\%%f
    call git pull
    cd ..
)
pause
```

If you want to specify the directory look at hawkeye's answer