# How to create permanent PowerShell Aliases

Tags: powershell

I want to create an `alias` of a `cmdlet` that doesn't expire after I close the current session of Powershell, let's say I have this alias :

```
C:\Users\Aymen> New-Alias Goto Set-Location
```

This perfectly creates the `Goto` alias, but I want to use it even after I close the current session, how can I achieve that.

**Note:**

The PowerShell Help system suggests that I can export the aliases I create, and import them next time I open a new session, actually that's not really what I'm looking, for, is there a direct clear way to keep having a alias after I create it through different sessions

Comment: IMO you're much better off putting scripts into the PATH. That way, the command will be available instantly to all your open shells and if you change it, the change will propagate to all subsequent uses without having to reload $profile or something.

Comment: one liner: `echo "Set-Alias bun pnpm" >> $profile && . $profile` , full answer somewhere below.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

**UPDATED - January 2021**

It's possible to store in a `profile.ps1` file any PowerShell code to be executed each time PowerShell starts. There are at least [6 different paths](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105003839/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) where to store the code depending on which user has to execute it. We will consider only 2 of them: the "all users" and the "only your user" paths (follow the previous link for further options).

To answer your question, you only have to create a `profile.ps1` file containing the code you want to be executed, that is:

```
New-Alias Goto Set-Location
```

and save it in the proper path:

- `"$Home\Documents"` (usually `C:\Users\<yourname>\Documents`): only your user will execute the code. This is the recommended location
  *You can quickly find your profile location by running `echo $profile` in PowerShell*
- `$PsHome` (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`): every user will execute this code

**IMPORTANT**: remember you need to restart your PowerShell instances to apply the changes.

**TIPS**

- If both paths contain a `profile.ps1` file, the all-users one is executed first, then the user-specific one. This means the user-specific commands will overwrite variables in case of duplicates or conflicts.
- Always put the code in the user-specific profile if there is no need to extend its execution to every user. This is safer because you don't pollute other users' space (usually, you don't want to do that).
  Another advantage is that you don't need administrator rights to add the file to your user-space (you do for anything in C:\Windows\System32).
- If you really need to execute the profile code for every user, mind that the `$PsHome` path is different for 32bit and 64bit instances of PowerShell. You should consider both environments if you want to **always** execute the profile code.

  The paths are:

  - `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` for the 64bit environment
  - `C:\Windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` for the 32bit one (Yeah I know, the folder naming is counterintuitive, but [it's correct](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/)).

Comment: no error it just did not work, i am not sure if this is a permissions issue. I did actually get it to work ( i should i commented earlier ) . I had to create the folder `\Users\{ME}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` and then add `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` non of the other paths works for me.

Comment: According to linked article using `"$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell"` and naming `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` restrict the scope to non-ISE and to current host, but shouldn't be a matter of permissions (same of `"$Home\Documents\profile.ps1" should apply`). Maybe it's not really so, I will give it a try, thank you for the information

Comment: Hi @Naigel, I must use this approach to make it work: http://superuser.com/questions/516700/bash-aliases-equivalent-for-powershell so the final solution for me was create the file for profile: `New-Item -path $profile -type file -force` that created the folder and file `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, no matter what I do. This ended up working for me: http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/78513-how-do-you-permanently-add-function-power-shell.html

Comment: @Naigel for alluser setup I needed to restart the machine, it may be better to update answer.

Comment: The best way to get the profile location might be to run "echo $profile" in your powershell window.

Comment: Remember to make a backup of your profile.ps1 file, as Windows Creators Update seems to clear the file at its default location!!

Comment: in my case (powershell 6.1.3 win7 64bits), ISE profile is C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1 and powershell is C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: additionally, I had to set the execution policy to `RemoteSigned`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

Comment: If you're using this for PowerShell Core, the `$PSHOME` will be where that tool is installed.

Comment: A better scheme to get the correct profile file:
1) Test the path: `Test-Path $Profile`
2) If necessary, create the file: `New-Item -Path $Profile -Type File -Force`
3) Edit the file: `notepad $Profile`

Comment: In short: `"New-Alias NAME COMMAND" >> $PROFILE`.

Comment: This answer was very helpfull. My way of getting an bash-like alias: (1) `notepad $PsHome\Profile.ps1` (2) inside notepad add `function my_alias_for_pws_foo(){ Set-Location }` (3) press enter & write `Set-Alias go my_alias_for_pws_foo` (4) save notepad, exit, exit & restart powershell (4) `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` if you did not already

Comment: using `Set-Alias` might be faster.

Answer (score 192):

It's not a good idea to add this kind of thing directly to your `$env:WINDIR` powershell folders, unless you truly want your alias to be global.
The recommended way is to add it to your personal profile:

```posh
cd $env:USERPROFILE\Documents
md WindowsPowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cd WindowsPowerShell
New-Item Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 -ItemType "file" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
powershell_ise.exe .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Now add your alias to the Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file that is now opened:

```posh
function Do-ActualThing {
    # do actual thing
}

Set-Alias MyAlias Do-ActualThing
```

Then save it, and refresh the current session with:

```
. $profile
```

**Note:**
Just in case, if you get permission issue like

> CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Try the below command and refresh the session again.

```posh
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: Great comment.  Very clear, although my powershell doesn't have touch.

Comment: @JustinB try `new-item`

Comment: In order to allow the execution of my profile script, I had to do one extra step.  Run Powershell as an Administrator, and execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`.  The `-Scope` option makes it a bit more secure.

Comment: This is a great method! Please not that the function itself also becomes available in the shell, so you don't really need the Set-Alias part. Just call the function `MyAlias`. Also, to pass on arguments, use `@Args`, eg `function gs { git status @Args }`

Comment: @Automatico I like being explicit about the `Set-Alias` because I like to name my methods using the appropriate PS conventions with the appropriate Verbs. But yes, if you're not picky, you can just name your method whatever you intend to invoke.

Comment: @zombat This is exactly I was struggling with, for hours. Thank you, I am done now.

Comment: Very clear, should be the accepted answer thank you!

Comment: **UPDATE 2022**: I had to use `$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\PowerShell` as folder for the profile file. (I'm using powershell V 7.2.2)

Comment: Thanks. Of course we cannot change Microsoft program settings without disabling security. Feels like home

Answer (score 77):

Open a Windows PowerShell window and type:

```
notepad $profile
```

Then create a function, such as:

```
function goSomewhereThenOpenGoogleThenDeleteSomething {
    cd C:\Users\
    Start-Process -FilePath "http://www.google.com"
    rm fileName.txt
}
```

Then type this under the function name:

```
Set-Alias google goSomewhereThenOpenGoogleThenDeleteSomething
```

Now you can type the word "google" into Windows PowerShell and have it execute the code within your function!

Comment: $profile doesn't seem to be a default environment variable in windows 10.  What is it supposed to be pointing to?

Comment: @wordsforthewise - The $PROFILE automatic variable stores the paths to the PowerShell profiles that are available in the current session. It is included in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: This was bar none the simplest solution provided.

Comment: I had to enable 'Enable PowerShell Scripts' (in another answer) to get this to work. Seriously super simple!

Comment: Great solution, worth noting that the file under $profile may not exist yet. Can be manually created though.

Comment: I got `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 is not digitally signed.` - meh, Microsoft's classic. Will use Mingw I guess)

Answer (score 44):

## 2018, Windows 10

You can link to any file or directory with the help of a simple PowerShell script.

#### Writing a file shortcut script

Open Windows PowerShell ISE.  In the script pane write:

```
New-Alias ${shortcutName} ${fullFileLocation}
```

Then head to the command-line pane. Find your PowerShell user profile address with `echo $profile`. Save the script in this address.

[image]

The script in PowerShell's profile address will run each time you open powershell. The shortcut should work with every new PowerShell window.

#### Writing a directory shortcut script

It requires another line in our script.

```
function ${nameOfFunction} {set-location ${directory_location}}
New-Alias ${shortcut} ${nameOfFunction}
```

The rest is exactly the same.

[image]

#### Enable PowerShell Scripts

By default PowerShell scripts are blocked. To enable them, open settings -> Update & Security -> For developers. Select Developer Mode (might require restart). 
[image: Selecting Developer Mode Windows 10].

Scroll down to the PowerShell section, tick the "Change execution policy ..." option, and apply.

[image: Enabling PowerShell scripts]

Comment: `echo $profile` is an awesome tip for helping finding the correct location to add the file. Thank you for the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 13):

I found that I can run this command:

```
notepad $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts
```

and it opens my default powershell profile (for Current User, All Hosts). I found that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1).

Then add an alias.  For example, here is my alias of `jn` for `jupyter notebook` (I hate typing out the cumbersome `jupyter notebook` every time):

```
Set-Alias -Name jn -Value C:\Users\words\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe
```

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to this list of possible locations...

This didn't work for me:
`\Users\{ME}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

However this did:
`\Users\{ME}\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

If you don't have a profile or you're looking to set one up, run the following command, it will create the folder/files necessary and even tell you where it lives! 

`New-Item -path $profile -type file -force`

Comment: that last command worked for me. I didn't have any of the previous directories mentioned

Answer (score 7):

to create the profile1.psl file, type in the following command:

**new-item $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts -ItemType file -Force**

to access the file, type in the next command:

**ise $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts**

*note* if you haven't done this before, you will see that you will not be 
able to run the script because of your execution policy, which you need to change to Unrestricted from Restricted (default).

to do that close the script and then type this command:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser**

then:

**RemoteSigned**

then this command again:

**ise $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts**

then finally type your aliases in the script, save it, and they should
run every time you run powershell, even after restarting your computer.

Comment: You probably want: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. Don't go recommending `Unrestricted`. Source:
http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/running-powershell-scripts-easy-1-2-3

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit fancy... but it works:

**Step 1:** Create a Powershell Profile:

```
FILE: install_profile.ps1
# THIS SCRIPT BLOWS AWAY YOUR DEFAULT POWERSHELL PROFILE SCRIPT
#   AND INSTALLS A POINTER TO A GLOBAL POWERSHELL PROFILE

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function print ([string]$msg)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $msg
}

print ""

# User's Powershell Profile
$psdir  = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell"
$psfile = $psdir + "\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"

print "Creating Directory: $psdir"
md $psdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | out-null

# this is your auto-generated powershell profile to be installed
$content = @(
    "",
    ". ~/Documents/tools/profile.ps1",
    ""
)

print "Creating File: $psfile"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($psfile, $content)

print ""

# Make sure Powershell profile is readable
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
```

**Step 2:** then in tools ~/Documents/tools/profile.ps1:

```
function Do-ActualThing {
    # do actual thing
}

Set-Alias MyAlias Do-ActualThing
```

**Step 3:**

$ Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
$ . ./install_profile.ps1

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of personal taste, but I prefer to store my aliases together in a separate file and call `Import-Alias` in the profile.

```
$profileDir = Split-Path $PROFILE -Parent
$profileFile = Join-Path $profileDir profile.ps1
$aliasFile = Join-Path $profileDir aliases.csv
New-Alias -Name npp -Value "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -Description "Notepad++"
Export-Alias -Name npp -Path $aliasFile -Append
ise $profileFile
```

Then in the ISE, put this line in your profile.ps1

```
Import-Alias -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot aliases.csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

## For the 1-Liner bros

> > > echo "Set-Alias bun pnpm" >> $profile && . $profile

this will run `pnpm` if you type `bun`, the `&& . $profile` will refresh current session, useful if some frameworks depend on other underlying package managers like you can also use to make ps1 and shell scripts compatible across OS,

- also killing and restarting pshell => these aliases are guranteed to persist, tested with terminal and vscode.

### if you want to inspect and manually edit (required vscode)

> code $profile

code is cli to open vscode iydk. use this for debug if you mess up pipe append :)

Answer (score 0):

Offering simplest solution:

1. Open powershell
2. Write to profile for all users: `notepad $PsHome\Profile.ps1`:

> function Goto() {
>
> #function name is alias, set of commands are the body
>
> Set-Location
>
> }
> 3. Save & exit notepad
> 4. Set powershell permissions: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
> 5. Restart powershell & write `goto`

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "Set-Alias ll dir" >> $profile
. $profile
```

[image]

Comment: Borked my $profile, had to open `"C:\Users\adamd\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"` in `notepad` and changed it from `s e t - ...` to `set-alias -name "unzip" -value "expand-archive"`.

Comment: Strange I tested in both Powershell 5 and 7 without problem. Perhaps your format will be more standard.