# Python 2 and 3 from Powershell

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, python-3.x, anaconda

I've installed `Python 3.5` using Anaconda and `2.7` using the following command:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

This successfully installed `2.7` as a separate environment with the Anaconda3 folder:

```
# original installation path for 3.5
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3

# path for 2.7 after conda create -n is run
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\py27
```

This works great as long as I'm using an IDE like Spyder or IPython Notebook, where I can choose which Python version. However, I have not been able to use `py27` (`Python 2.7`) in the PowerShell. I've tried using:

```
activate py27
```

yet `python` command still fires up `3.5` and `py27` causes this error:

```
py27 : The term 'py27' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1 + py27
    + ~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo   : ObjectNotFound: (py27:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried everything I know or have read here on SO, but nothing I've tried has been able to resolve the issue. I'm not sure if this helps, but here is my PATH variable for reference:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;[stuff in between];C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\p27;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\p27\Scripts\;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\p27\Library\bin
```

Comment: What is `activate`? If it is a batch file, the environment variables it sets will not propagate to PowerShell. To fix this, you can use the `Invoke-CmdScript` function from [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, `activate` is the command I found here on SO, to "activate" the `2.7` environment within the Anaconda3 installation. It is the most common solution I read on the forum. However, even though the command ran with no problem in the PowerShell, it didn't actually allow me to run `2.7` from the command line. Here is an example post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9)

Comment: Again: If `activate` is a batch file (cmd.exe shell script) and it sets environment variables, you will need to run it using the `Invoke-CmdScript` function in the article.

Comment: To recapitulate differently: PowerShell can run a batch file, but if the batch file sets environment variable values that are supposed to persist after the batch file terminates, said batch file won't work properly in PowerShell because the cmd.exe process that ran the batch file terminated. The workaround is to "capture" the environment variable changes that the batch file makes, then propagate the changes to PowerShell. That is the purpose of the `Invoke-CmdScript` function in the aforementioned article.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart , thanks for the script. I'm sorry I'm just getting back to this. I've read the article and downloaded the script. However, I have no clue where to put it: where do I put the text file and are there any further commands to run once I've got it in the right place?

Comment: I would recommend reading some introductory training material about PowerShell. I published some articles (the links to which are posted in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1ba3ecfb-2dac-4960-ba75-0b5f5f0dc090/)) that may be of help.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, thanks. I've got it installed, sourced it and made the functions available. `activate` is a `.bat` file that is installed with th Anaconda python distribution. The purpose of the file is to switch between the 2 and 3 environments. I just have not been able to get the `Invoke-CmdScript` to function. I pass `Invoke-CmdScript .\activate.bat` but nothing appears to take place.

Comment: You would have to add the `Invoke-CmdScript` function into your current scope. You can do this by dot-sourcing a script file (see the section `Using Dot Source Notation with Scope` - run `help about_Scopes` in PowerShell) that contains the function, or you can add the function your PowerShell profile (run the command `help about_Profiles` in PowerShell for more information).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I added the Environment.ps1 directory to my PATH variable, dot-sourced the Environment.ps1 file, which gave me access to the `Invoke-CmdScript` function. At this point, I ran the command `Invoke-CmdScript .\activate.bat`. I get `'.\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` in return.

Comment: I can't see your screen, but `.\activate.bat` means "the copy of `activate.bat` this is sitting in the current directory." If `activate.bat` is not in the current directory, you need to tell PowerShell where it is.

Comment: Short story: I've fixed it, and I really appreciate your help. I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to close this question with the following solution: use `Cmd.exe` or use the `PowerShell` with Bill Stewart's `Invoke-CmdScript` (see comments). First, the simpler solution using the `Command Prompt (Cmd.exe)`:

```
# to activate
C:\Users\me\> activate py2

# to deactivate and return to Python 3.5
C:\Users\me\> deactivate
```

Which activates the Python 2.7 environment I created using `conda`. Now, for the `Powershell` version. First, go this [site](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell) and download the `Environment.ps1` script. For me, it downloaded as text file, so I opened the file, removed the `.txt` extension and replaced it with `.ps1`. So, let's say I saved `Environment.ps1` in the following directory `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\invoke_cmdscript`. Take this path and add it to the PATH user variable within the Environment variables form. Now, the commands to type in your `PowerShell` window:

```
# dot-source my file
. Environment.ps1

# activate 2.7 environment (if not in the directory of activate.bat, specify full path)
Invoke-CmdScript .\activate.bat py2


# deactivate 2.7 environment (same note about current directory and full paths)
Invoke-CmdScript .\deactivate.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want python 3 to run every time you type python3, and
python 2 to run every time you type python2:

Depending on where your executables are, simply make some aliases 
using the following codes:

for python2:

**Set-Alias python2 C:\Users\yourusername\python2location\python.exe**

for python3:

**Set-Alias python3 C:\Users\yourusername\python3location\python.exe**

to learn how to make them permanent, check my response at the [following page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases/41348988#41348988)

Answer (score 0):

From your PATH variable it appears you created the py27 env with the name "p27"
Try 'activate p27'
You can always double check the env names by looking in the "envs" directory in your conda installation folder.

Comment: I've used the 'activate p27' to no avail. To be honest, I'm not sure what steps I'm supposed to take after activating the environment. For  example, to use the python version in p27 after activating, do I use python, python2, p27, or py -2 to run python 2.7? I've tried all of them, and nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround if you love powershell compared to cmd without dealing with changing 'stuff' is to type:

```
cmd #to get internally into command prompt from ps
activate envname
powershell #to get back
```