# npm install save by default

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

It happened too many times that I forgot to add `--save` when installing node modules. Is there a way to append this option by default? So that whenever I type `npm install <package>` the package is added to dependencies in `package.json`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found out that `npm` has configuration flags. Setting `save=true` does exactly what I need. You can add it to `.npmrc` file (in user's home directory) or invoke a command:

```
npm config set save=true
```

Answer (score 36):

From npm5 , npm will save by default . https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5108

Answer (score 2):

### Mac/Linux

make an alias inside `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias npmi="npm install --save"
//shorter version
alias npmi="npm i -S"
```

then just type, so that it will automatically save it to package json

```
npmi mongoose
```

### Windows

same thing, make alias, read more here https://superuser.com/a/49194

```
doskey npmi=npm i -S $*
```

Comment: What about Windows users? ;)

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about `doskey`. However, your solution is missing `$*` - without it the package name won't be passed as an argument.

Comment: I don't have Windows, didn't test it, so referenced to another answer, feel free to improve this answer :)

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work but thanks to the link you provided I learnt that adding `$*` solves the issue.

Comment: @LukaszWiktor I suggest powershell alias - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914795/2115619