# Installing react router but does not update package.json file

Tags: reactjs, react-router, npm-install

Installing `react-router-dom`, after showing to many warning message and it does not update the `package.json` file. `Package.json` file in side dependencies object block dos not show `reac-router-dom` version information.

React Router:

```
npm i react-router-dom
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Linux\IDE\All-Workspace\JavaScript-Workspace\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Linux\IDE\All-Workspace\JavaScript-Workspace\package.json'
npm WARN @webpack-contrib/config-loader@1.2.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @webpack-contrib/schema-utils@1.0.0-beta.0 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router@4.3.1 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
tpm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer depealled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
|pm WARN webpack-command@0.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.| ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependenc installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
ipm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No description
es yourself.
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.x.x but none is
ipm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No license field.
nstalled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                   les\fsevents):
npm WARN webpack-command@0.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.4.0 but noneevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"wiis installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-dom@4.3.1 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none isnpm WARN webpack-command@0.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.4.0 but none
 is installed. You must install pe
er dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-dom@4.3.1 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is
 installed. You must install peer
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-command@0.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.4.0 but none dep: is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-dom@4.3.1 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No descriptionnpm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No repository field.
npm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No README data
npm WARN JavaScript-Workspace No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
+ react-router-dom@4.3.1updated 1 package and audited 11195 packages in 13.378sfound 0 vulnerabilities
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lyricfinder_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the package-lock file

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `--save` or `-S` as an option to npm install like this:
`npm install -S react-router-dom`. 
Then your telling npm to add it to package.json.
Or if you want to save it as a dev dependency you add a `-D`

**Edit**

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441625/5997891, and the comment below, from `npm` version 5 , the `npm install` command saves packages by default.

Comment: Newer versions of npm save by default

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was not in the root directory when I run `npm i react-router -S`

I later cd into the root directory and all was good.