# Simulate python3 shell commands behavior in windows powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, path

I work on an api that run python3 scripts like `python3 <scriptname.py>`. This api initially run on a linux system. Unfortunately I make the local development of it on a windows. Is there a way to simulate this behaviour so that when I run in powershell `python3 -V` it give me the version of python.

I have allready python 3 installed on my computer. I tried to add the path to my `python.exe` to the system variables with for variable the string `python3`. But after registering and restarting powershell and type `python3 -V` I still get the error that «python3» is not recognized as a command applet name.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once python is in your path, you can define a PowerShell alias for python3.

```
PS > New-Alias python3 python
PS > python3 -V
python 3.6.5
```

In order to have this alias as a permanent one, refer to this question: [Permanent PowerShell Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases).

Answer (score 0):

I found tricky solution.
Once python is in your path, go to python installed path and copy python.exe and named duplicated one as python3.exe

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution but this is really a tricky one :) I definitively recommend [yakobyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9919541/yakobyd)'s answer.