# How can I use Powershell to open a file with spaces in it in an auxiliary application, using a function?

Tags: windows, powershell

```
Function npp {
    Param([String]$filepath)
    start 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' &($filepath)
}

Function nteract {
    $file = $args[0]
    start 'D:\Program Files\nteract\nteract.exe' &($file)
}
```

I wrote two beginner functions for the purpose of recreating the much easier aliases in bash and fish.  I have tried two ways of capturing a file argument as shown above.  Neither of them work.  Instead I receive the following.

Say I am opening the file '.\01 Getting started.ipynb' in nteract.

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Microsoft.PowerShell.Man…
.\01. Getting started.ipynb
```

This displays in my console, and opens a default instance of nteract with an empty notebook.  The same happens with Notepad++ with other files.

Insert a complaint here about how confusing it is to get this functionality working compared to Linux shells.  What am I doing wrong?

-==-

EDIT: This question has been answered sufficiently, but I did notice strange behavior the first time I commented out the functions I wrote in my profile.

```
PS D:\julitory\JuliaBoxTutorials\introductory-tutorials\intro-to-julia> . $profile
PS D:\julitory\JuliaBoxTutorials\introductory-tutorials\intro-to-julia> nteract '.\02. Strings.ipynb'

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost
.\02. Strings.ipynb
```

For some reason, this occured the first time I commented them out.  So I uncommented them, and it began to work again... then, the next time I commented them, they continued to work.  I think I'm just too tired for this, but thanks all.

Comment: `&($filepath)`? Do you mean `{$filepath}`? I assume that is your argument list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell has [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1) for that purpose. Define, for example:

```
Set-Alias -Name nteract -Value "D:\Program Files\nteract\nteract.exe"
```

Then use the alias as:

```
nteract ".\01 Getting started.ipynb"
```

Aliases defined this way are only available during the current PowerShell session. For ways to make them persist see [How to create permanent PowerShell Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases)
.

Comment: I have been stupid enough to somehow not try this with my nteract alias, even though I actually had earlier _already written a working alias for notepad++_ and somehow forgotten about it.  I was too caught up in my own head.  Thanks!  EDIT: I spoke too soon.  Apparently, it only works if I have both the functions and the aliases defined... it doesn't work with just the aliases.