# PowerShell Alias when connected to a remote Exchange Server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a script to connect to my exchange server remotely and create some alias for commonly used commands.

I connect to exchange using:

`$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ServerFQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential`

`Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking`

If I add to the bottom of this script:

`New-Alias -Name "GR" -Value Get-Recipient`

I see no error message, but no alias is created. If I run my script to connect to Exchange, and then run the **New-Alias** command in the terminal, the alias creates as expected.

I assume I am missing something fundamental regarding Sessions or scope, and any help gratefully received.

Comment: > Aliases created by using `New-Alias` are not saved after you exit the session or close PowerShell.

Comment: You could create files storing your aliases and call them when you launch your connection. The answer regarding how to achieve this can be found here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases>