# Struggling to set multiple aliases in Powershell, VSCODE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, alias

When I try to set an alias where I will type w++17 it should correspond to `w++17 -g++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -fmax-errors=3`

I do it in Poweshell terminal using VSCODE. When I try to set the alias I do:

```
Set-Alias -Name w++17 -Value g++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -fmax-errors=3
```

I get the following error:

```
Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'main.cpp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Alias -Name w++17 -Value g++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -We ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand
```

It looks like I cant set an alias containing multiple values/arguments?

Comment: Use a wrapper function instead

Comment: Is there a tutorial with examples on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this wrapper..

```cpp
Function wplusplus { (w++17 -g++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -fmax-errors=3) }

Set-Alias -Name wpp17 -Value wplusplus
```

Comment: Oh really nice! The only problem is that when I restart vscode all the functions and aliases that I have created gets removed and I have to define them again. Can I not save them?

Comment: check out this StackOverflow post on profiles; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases
Please mark answer as such if it helped you, thanks!