# symfony - symfony CLI is installed but path in environnement variable not working

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, symfony-cli

In the environnement variable, then in system variable, I edited the path and added

> C:\Users\Tobe\symfony-cli_windows_amd64\symfony.exe

then I saved it and exit with all the OK messages. I restarted my console just in case too.

But in a console I still can't use "symfony" command line, but symfony CLI is working if I use the complete command :

> C:\Users\Tobe\symfony-cli_windows_amd64\symfony.exe

What is wrong?

I tried to install symfony CLI with scoop, but I couldn't install scoop because the commandes in the quick start didn't worked (

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser # Optional: Needed to run a remote script the first time
>
> irm get.scoop.sh | iex

)

Both

> Set-ExecutionPolicy

and

> irm

were not recognized.

Comment: Your environment variable for the path should include just the folder name, not the executable.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thank you, both C:\Users\Tobe\symfony-cli_windows_amd64\ or C:\Users\Tobe\symfony-cli_windows_amd64 seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and the unique solution i founded is to make an powershell permanent alias with the full path to "symfony"..

Follow theses steps :
[How to create permanent powershell-aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases)