# Keep multiple Git repositories up to date?

Tags: git

I and my coworkers are working on multiple repositories. They are all independent, and do not share the same path. For instance

- C:\Website A
- C:\Website B
- C:\Website C
- D:\GitClientTools
- C:\Users\me\ServerFiles

Someone may clone repositories to different folders.

Is there a way or tool that automatically periodically pull repositories?

I understand if working directoy has changes, pull may fail. In that case, giving a notification is fine.

I looked at SourceTree and Git Extensions. They can auto fetch, but still require a manual pull or merge.

I don't want to every time go to each of the repository and run the pull.

Comment: Read about Google Repo tool. maybe it could help: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/

Comment: @Yakov For the record, Google Repo requires Python fcntl modul, which Windows doesn't have. I'm using Windows, so Repo doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git pull for multiple repos on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223630/how-to-git-pull-for-multiple-repos-on-windows)