# Git Pull for Multiple Repositories with Batch file

Tags: windows, git, github, command

I am trying to run a batch file,

which will go to grandparent folder, and do git pull for all its child repository directories. For some reason, this is not working. How can I get this functioning?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET parent=%~dp0
ECHO parent=%parent%
FOR %%a IN ("%parent:~0,-1%") DO SET grandparent=%%~dpa
ECHO grandparent=%grandparent%

ECHO %grandparent%

FOR /D %%G in (%grandparent%) Do cd %%G & call git pull & cd ..

TIMEOUT 10
```

Using following as reference:

[How to git pull for multiple repos on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223630/how-to-git-pull-for-multiple-repos-on-windows)

Using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the output of `dir` command to iterate over the directories in your `%grandparent%` folder, something like:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (`dir /A:D-H /B "%grandparent%"`) Do (
    pushd "%grandparent%%%G"
    git pull
    popd
)
```

Hope it helps.