# How did I cross the streams, and how can I uncross them?

Tags: git

I've been using git happily for the better part of a year, and our team is using the git-flow model (although not git-flow itself). Last week I created a release branch and have been happily merging the changes back into the development/unstable branch - that is until something very strange happened today.

Somehow, the release branch got *hyper-merged*, or something. I honestly can't think of a better way to describe it than "crossing the streams". Here's a visual from Git Extensions:

[image: Crossed Streams GitEx]

I'm obfuscating most of the commit comments, sorry. But starting from the bottom, you can clearly see the development branch on the *left* and the release branch on the *right* being periodically merged into it. Until about halfway through, when I must have done something wrong with the merge, because at that point the release branch *literally* merged with the development branch - they actually appear to *share* a merge commit that should only have been on the development branch.

GitHub presents a slightly clearer view:

[image: Crossed Streams GitHub]

This doesn't look so unusual, except for the fact that the blue and black lines are supposed to be the *same* branch. Just to tick off the obvious:

- There are commits from other contributors, but the specific commits in question are from me. I know I can trust the commit messages.
- The commit messages *all* say the same thing: "Merge branch 'release-1.3' into develop." So I know I didn't, for example, accidentally merge the development branch into the release branch instead.
- I never created any new branches or used any commands other than `git pull --rebase`, `git commit`, and `git merge`. I wasn't experimenting or trying to do anything creative with the repository.

It *looks* like I dropped the original `release-1.3` branch and created a new one from the `develop` branch near the middle. But I *didn't* do that. The `release-1.3` branch has been active the whole time. I swear that the blue and black commits really are the same branch and that I never did any merges other than merging them both into the development (pink) branch.

So I have two questions:

1. **How is this even possible?** I understand *technically* how it is possible, with git commits being graph nodes and all that, but I can't quite figure out how this happened from a *procedural* point of view. What mistake could I have made that would cause this, and how can I avoid doing it again?
2. **How can I get these branches untangled**, so that I don't have a bunch of half-finished code from the unstable branch in my squeaky-clean release branch? It should just look like two parallel lines occasionally connected by merges. Preferably, I'd like to do this *without* a forced push or destructive rebase, since this is a shared repository, although it's a small team and a private repository so I can get people to re-clone if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Tempted to +1 this just for the hilarious title, but I'll try to restrain myself :D

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help it: [Don't cross the streams](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyaLZHiJJnE); [Cross the streams](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OOF0FpKiYk).

Comment: If you can, please post your reflogs (for `HEAD`, `develop`, and `release-1.3`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The possibilities

I can think of a couple of ways this could have happened.

- **Fast-forward merge.**  I believe this to be the most likely cause.  This is what I believe happened:

  1. `release-1.3` was merged into `develop`
  2. immediately after, `develop` was fast-forward merged into `release-1.3`

  That's all.  `release-1.3` was merged to `develop`, then before any additional commits were made on `release-1.3` someone merged `develop` into `release-1.3`.  When possible, `git` does a fast-forward merge by default (a "feature" that does the wrong thing half the time), which is why the graph looks confusing.

  Note that a fast-forward merge leaves no direct evidence in the resulting graph.  Unlike a regular merge, a fast-forward merge does not create a new commit object, and no existing commit is modified.  A fast-forward merge simply adjusts the branch reference to point to an existing commit.

  Even though there is no direct evidence of a fast-forward merge, the fact that you can reach that one merge commit by following each branch's first-parent path strongly indicates that this was a result of a fast-forward merge.
- **Accidental `git branch` instead of `git checkout`.** On a project I was working on, another developer that was new to Git made the mistake of typing `git branch foo` in an attempt to switch to branch `foo`.  This is a perfectly natural mistake, and one that even an expert can make when tired.  Anyway, this mistake eventually resulted in something that looked just like a fast-forward merge even though `git merge` was never typed.  A similar thing could have happened here.  This is how the scenario plays out:

  1. The user has the `develop` branch checked out, and `develop` happens to be pointing to the merge commit that is at the center of this mystery.
  2. The user wishes to switch to the `release-1.3` branch to do some work, but accidentally types `git branch release-1.3` instead of `git checkout release-1.3`.
  3. Because it is a fresh clone, there is no local `release-1.3` branch yet (only `origin/release-1.3`).   Thus, Git happily creates a new local branch named `release-1.3` that is pointing at that same merge commit.
  4. Some time passes while the user edits some files.
  5. Preparing to commit, the user runs `git status`.  Because the current branch is still `develop` and not `release-1.3`, Git prints "On branch develop".
  6. The user is caught by surprise, and thinks, "Didn't I switch to release-1.3 a long time ago?  Oh well, I must have forgotten to switch branches."
  7. The user runs `git checkout release-1.3`, this time remembering the correct command.
  8. The user creates a commit and runs `git push`.
  9. Git's default push behavior (see `push.default` in `git help config`) is `matching`, so even though `release-1.3` doesn't have a configured upstream branch, `git push` chooses the upstream's `release-1.3` branch to push to.
  10. The new version of `release-1.3` is a descendant of the previous `release-1.3`, so the remote repository happily accepts the push.

  This is all it would take to produce the graph you provided in your question.

#### Assuming `develop` was intentionally merged into `release-1.3`

If the merge of `develop` into `release-1.3` was intentional (someone made a conscious decision that `develop` was good enough to ship), this is perfectly normal and correct.  Despite the visual differences, the blue and black lines are both on the `release-1.3` branch; the blue line just happens to *also* be on the `develop` branch.

The only thing wrong is that it's a little awkward for someone reviewing the history to figure out what's going on (you wouldn't have this question otherwise).  To prevent this from happening again, follow these rules of thumb:

- If you are merging two differently-named branches (e.g., `develop` and `release-1.3`, then **always** do `git merge --no-ff`.
- If you are merging two versions of the same branch (e.g., `develop` and `origin/develop`), then **always** do `git merge --ff-only`.  If that fails because you can't fast-forward, then it's time for `git rebase`.

If you had followed the above rules of thumb, then the graph would have looked like this:

```
*   (develop)
| * (release-1.3)
* | Merge...
|\|
| * Added...
| * using ...
* | adding...
| * Hide s...
* | Date ...
* | updati...
* | Candi...
| * Locali...
| * <---- merge commit that would have been created by
|/|      'git merge' had you used the '--no-ff' option
* | Merge...
|\|
| * Un-ign...
| * Added...
* | Merge...
|\|
| * Remov...
| * Move...
* | Fixed...
```

Notice how that extra merge commit makes the history much more readable.

#### If the merge of `develop` into `release-1.3` was a mistake

Doh!  Looks like you have some rebasing and force-pushing to do.  This will not make the other users of this repository happy.

Here's how you can fix it:

1. Run `git checkout release-1.3`.
2. Find the sha1 of that middle commit (where the two branches come together).  Let's call it `X`.
3. Run `git rebase --onto X^2 X`.  The resulting graph will look like this:

   ```
   *     (develop)
   |   * (release-1.3)
   *   | Merge...
   |\  |
   | * | Added...
   | | * Added...
   | * | using ...
   | | * using ...
   * | | adding...
   | * | Hide s...
   | | * Hide s...
   * | | Date ...
   * | | updati...
   * | | Candi...
   | * | Locali...
   |/  * Locali...
   *  / Merge...
   |\|
   | * Un-ign...
   | * Added...
   * | Merge...
   |\|
   | * Remov...
   | * Move...
   * | Fixed...
   ```

   This fixes the `release-1.3` branch, but notice how you now have two versions of the `release-1.3` commits.  The next steps will remove these duplicates from the `develop` branch.
4. Run `git checkout develop`.
5. Run `git branch temp` to act as a temporary placeholder for this commit.
6. Run `git reset --hard HEAD^^` to remove two commits from the `develop` branch: the tip `develop` commit and the commit merging the old version of `release-1.3` into `develop`.  We'll restore that tip commit later.
7. Run `git merge --no-ff release-1.3^` to merge the second commit on the new `release-1.3` branch and its ancestors into `develop`.
8. Run `git cherry-pick temp` to bring back the tip commit that was removed in step #6.
9. Run `git branch -D temp` to get rid of the temporary placeholder branch.  Your graph should now look like this:

   ```
   *   (develop)
   | * (release-1.3)
   * | Merge...
   |\|
   | * Added...
   | * using ...
   * | adding...
   | * Hide s...
   * | Date ...
   * | updati...
   * | Candi...
   | * Locali...
   * | Merge...
   |\|
   | * Un-ign...
   | * Added...
   * | Merge...
   |\|
   | * Remov...
   | * Move...
   * | Fixed...
   ```
10. Run `git push -f origin release-1.3 develop` to force-update the upstream branches.

#### Preventing this from happening again in the future

If you have control over the upstream repository and can install some hooks, you can create a hook that rejects any pushes where the old version of the branch isn't reachable by starting at the new version of the branch and walking the first-parent path.  This also has the advantage of rejecting [those stupid commits created by `git pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316602/712605).

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because it does have a lot of good and detailed information (and I'm particularly interested in *how* one might execute on the last paragraph, using GitHub). I do however feel compelled to point out that #2 did **not** happen, as I stated in the question. It just didn't. It's not in the commit messages, it's not in the log, it's not in the reflog which I have but forgot to bring home. What I do see is a *rebase* onto a commit that was supposed to be in the development branch, which is still mystifying but at least gives me a clue.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Fast-forward merges don't produce new commit objects, so there wouldn't be any commit messages suggesting that a fast-forward merge happened.  The reflog would show the fast-forward merge though.  I updated my answer and added another possible explanation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not sure, beyond pure speculation. If you can provide a `git log --decorate --graph --all --oneline` and a `git reflog release-1.3` (and perhaps a shell history) we might be able to help.
2. This does involve a force push. Talk to your teammates about this. I don't know your hashes of these commits since you haven't provided them. Replace `<blah>` with the corresponding hash.

   ```
   git branch -m release-1.3 old-release-1.3
   git checkout -b release-1.3 <Un-ign> # the last good commit on the release branch
   # This will replay those five commits onto our new release-1.3 branch
   git rebase --onto release-1.3 <Merge> old-release-1.3 # the merge just above "Un-ign"
   # Verify that release-1.3 now looks correct
   # You'll need the -f. Be careful with force pushes, run -n first
   git push [-n|-f] origin release-1.3
   ```

Comment: `--onto` seems to have done the trick. I had to also do a `rebase -i` on the `develop` branch to get rid of a bunch of duplicate commits and orphaned merges.