# Git merging on pull even though I've not modified the file

Tags: git, version-control, sass

I am a developer working on a project along side some front end designers. They have some SASS '.scss' files that I never touch.

Despite me not modifying, these files regularly merge rather than simply download - if I'm not mistaken, this is not the expected behaviour?

I had assumed that if a file has not changed, git should simply replace the file rather than merge.

Comment: This might be due to permission issue. Some times even if there is no change in the file, it is still shown in the diff and even get in merge . You can just check the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the 'merge commits'. git pull is actually a git fetch followed by a git merge.So you will see the 'merge commit' every time you do a 'git pull' (correct me if I am wrong).  its always better to use git pull --rebase so that you the 'merge commit' wont appear in your logs.

[In what cases could `git pull` be harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316601/in-what-cases-could-git-pull-be-harmful) : this thread contains a lot of information regarding this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That isn't actually what I'm talking about. 

I'm getting actual merge prompts where I'm asked to fill out a merge comment, with the occasional merge failure.